# C++ Eigen:: Unable to Access Matrix after Passing to Class

Tags: c++, matrix, pass-by-reference, eigen

I am trying to pass an Eigen::Matrix to a class by reference and access the elements in it.

When I try to access the matrix again in both main function and in the class, it fails and gives segmentation error if the matrix size is large. I used a debugger to check the values of the matrix and found that the elements of the matrix were not accessible.

Below is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
Eigen::MatrixXf A = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(3,640); //this is OK
//Eigen::MatrixXf A = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(3,640*480); //but not this

std::cout << "in main A col " << A.cols() << " row " << A.rows()
          << "\nA\n" << A.col(100) << "\n\n";

model.testLoadMat(A);

model.testReadMat();

std::cout << "in main testMat col " << model.testMat->cols() << " row " << model.testMat->rows()
          << "\ntestMat\n" << model.testMat->col(100) << "\n\n"; //fails here if A is large

return 0;
```

**model.h**

```
class model
{
    public:
        const Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic> *testMat;
        void testLoadMat(const Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic> &tMat);
        void testReadMat();
}
```

**model.cpp**

```
void model::testLoadMat(const Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic> &tMat)
{
    testMat = &tMat;

    std::cout << "in testLoadMat col " << testMat->cols() << " row " << testMat->rows()
           << "\ntestMat\n" << testMat->col(100) << "\n\n";
}

void model::testReadMat()
{
    std::cout << "in testReadMat col " << testMat->cols() << " row " << testMat->rows()
           << "\ntestMat\n" << testMat->col(100) << "\n\n"; //fails here if A is large
}
```

They still give the correct number of rows and columns but I just can't access the elements inside.

Why is it not working and how can I solve it? Otherwise, is there any better method to do this properly?

Also, I notice that the time to execute `testLoadMat()` increases with the matrix size. Does it mean that I am doing the "passing by reference" incorrectly?

Comment: Which call specifically makes it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for `A` in `main` is `Eigen::MatrixXf`, or `Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>`.  Your `testLoadMat` function wants a reference to a `Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic>` object.  Since these are different types, a temporary Matrix of the correct type is created, and it is a reference to this temporary object that is passed to `testLoadMat`.  `testLoadMat` then stores a pointer to this temporary Matrix, which becomes invalid when the function returns and the temporary Matrix is destroyed.  When you call `testReadMat`, you dereference this invalid pointer, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

The fix is to change the parameter type of your `testLoadMat` function to match the type you're passing in.

Comment: I got it work by changing all of the variable types to `Eigen::MatrixXf`.
Just two more questions:
1) Why the code works fine when the matrix size is small? I can still access the columns of the matrix.
2) Is there any advantage of using `Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic>` if I know the row number beforehand or it is just advisable to use `Eigen::MatrixXf` for all cases?

Comment: @mjfoo21 1) You got lucky.  The memory previously used by the matrix has not been reused (so it still has the data it had) and gives the appearance of still working.  2) Performance.  The more concrete data you include in the template type, the fewer memory allocations need to be done.  See the Eigen documentation on the `Matrix` template for more.